# facebook comment on my website

Tags: php, facebook

How to create comment system from facebook and when the comment from the form in my site is submited the submited things to go as comment to facebook user accout and to my database.I saw this in a lot of sites.

Comment: Have you looked at http://developers.facebook.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Add the comments plugin by getting the code from their [comments social plugin page.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

Then, subscribe to the comments.create event in javascript, per Facebooks Event subscribe documentation. Inside the callback, replace the sample alert below with code to call back to your server to log to your database.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
  alert('JSON representation of Facebook response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try google?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

But i don't know if you can get that data into your database directly, maybe via the Graph API

Answer (score 2):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Read their documentation on it, its very complete and well written so that everybody may use it well.

Comment: I saw that but, my idea is the form actualy, so haw i sed not only to send the info to the facebook page but to my database to, like submited form.And here is like iframe or smth..

Comment: @shalamhez: You could use the FB API to retrieve the comment from FB after it's posted: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490